# what is the value of angle $a$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

> what is the value of angle   $a$
>   [image]

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I have a brute force answer, but the work is awful. I'm probably missing some cool trick that makes it easy. At least the answer is nice.

Comment: @prayer smith -- (1) Where is the problem from?; (2) Have you tried anyhing? If so, can you show your work up to the point where you got stuck?

Comment: This is a good question. Who is gave -1 ? I will give +1 and I will try for a synthetic solution.

Comment: Not me. -1 is probably due to the fact that OP did not show any effort.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(We are grateful to Suleyman Soyler for this solution, he is a math teacher.)

By power of $D$ w.r.t given circle: $|DC|^2=|DE|\cdot |DB|$ and $|AD|=|DC|$. Therefore

$$|AD|^2=|DE|\cdot |DB|$$

implies $\triangle ADB \sim \triangle EDA$ (by side-angle-side). Hence we find that

$$ \angle ABD = \angle EAD \tag{1}$$

$$ \angle DEA = \angle DAB = 36^\circ \tag{2}$$

Now, let's draw circumcircle of $\triangle AED$ and ray $[DF$. Let's say intersection of them $K$. By inscribed angles

$$ \angle EAD = \angle EKD \tag{3}$$

and 
$$ \angle DKA = \angle DEA = 36^\circ \tag{4}$$

By sum of interior angles of $\triangle ADK$, we find $\angle KAF =36^\circ$ and therefore $|FB|=|FA|=|FK|$. Then

$$\angle FBK = \angle FKB = 54^\circ \tag{5}$$

On the other hand, $(1)$ and $(3)$ implies that $KFEB$ a cyclic quadrilateral. Thus $$ \angle DEF = \angle FKB = 54^\circ $$

[image: 54]

Comment: Bravo Suleyman Soyler! Such an elegant solution!

Comment: Glad to see someone can prove it via geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: $\angle FED = \alpha = 54^\circ .$ In the solution, we will use $\cos 54^\circ = \sqrt{\dfrac{5-\sqrt 5}{8}} $ and $\cos 36^\circ = \dfrac{\sqrt 5 -1}{4}$.

[image: figure]

Without loss of generality we assume that $|AD|=|AF|=2.$ By $\cos 36^\circ = \dfrac{\sqrt 5 -1}{4}$ and cosine theorem in $\triangle ADF$, we find $|DF|=\sqrt 5 -1.$ Let's say that $|DE|=x, |EB|=y, |FE|=z.$ By power of point $D$ with respect to the circle:

$$x(x+y)=2^2 \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, by cosine theorem in $\triangle ADB$: $(x+y)^2=2^2+4^2-2\cdot 2\cdot 4 \cdot \cos 36^\circ$ and

$$ (x+y)^2=16-4\sqrt 5 \tag{2} $$

If we solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we can find

$$x=\dfrac 2{\sqrt{4 - \sqrt5}}, \   \  \ y=\dfrac {2(3-\sqrt 5)}{\sqrt{4 - \sqrt5}} \tag{3} $$

Now, let's apply Stewart's theorem in $\triangle BDF$: $z^2 =\dfrac{x\cdot |BF|^2 + y\cdot |DF|^2}{x+y}-xy$ and we can calculate $z$, by exhausting operations.

In last step, $\angle DEF = \alpha$ and $\cos\alpha = \dfrac{x^2+z^2-|DF|^2}{2 x z}$ and therefore $\cos \alpha = \sqrt{\dfrac{5-\sqrt 5}{8}} \implies \alpha = 54^\circ $.